# Are these different telnet commands?

Tags: http, telnet

What does these both commands do?

```
telnet www.abc.ac.in 80
```

vs

```
telnet www.abc.ac.in http
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same.  They both use `telnet` to connect to port 80 on a server in India (which does not seem to exist).  The port to connect to can be given as a number (`80`) or as a symbolic name (`http`).  The default port for the HTTP protocol is port 80. You can see the mapping between these in your `/etc/services` file.